Как отформатировать данные в таблице Excel?
Есть файл с таблице Excel в которой находятся данные следующего типа:
россия, московская область, ленинский район, г.видное, ул.заводская, д.6, кв.22 
643,163000,78,,санктпетербург г,,офицерский пер,8б,,5 
646602, россия, омская обл. , горьковский р-н, с. астыровка, ул. комсомольская, д. 17, кв. 1 
656000, россия, г. барнаул, ул. эмилии алексеевой, д. 6, кв. 108

Из таких данных после прохождения через программу должны получится такие:
г. Видное, ул. Заводская, д.6, кв. 22 
г. Санкт-Петербург, пер. Офицерский, д. 8Б, кв. 5 
с. Астыровка, ул. Комсомольская, д. 17, кв. 1 
г. Барнаул, ул. Эмилии Алексеевой, д. 6, кв. 108

Не могу представить как такое решить, может есть какие-то готовые решения в Excel или библиотеки в Python?
Моя попытка написать на Python (результат получается 50/50):
import re


def parse_address(address):
    pattern = r'(?P<postal_code>\d{6})?,?\s*(?P<country>[^,]*),?\s*(?P<region>[^,]*),?\s*(?P<district>[^,]*),?\s*(?P<locality>[^,]*),?\s*(?P<street>[^,]*),?\s*(?P<house>[^,]*),?\s*(?P<apartment>[^,]*)'

    # Убираем лишние пробелы и запятые
    address = re.sub(r'\s*,\s*', ',', address)
    address = re.sub(r',+', ',', address)
    address = address.strip(', ')

    match = re.match(pattern, address)

    if match:
        address_dict = match.groupdict()
        address_dict = {k: v.strip() if v else "Не указано" for k, v in address_dict.items()}
        return address_dict
    else:
        return None


addresses = [
    "россия, московская область, ленинский район, г.видное, ул.заводская, д.6, кв.22",
    "643,163000,78,,санктпетербург г,,офицерский пер,8б,,5",
    "646602, россия, омская обл. , горьковский р-н, с. астыровка, ул. комсомольская, д. 17, кв. 1",
    "656000, россия, г. барнаул, ул. эмилии алексеевой, д. 6, кв. 108"
]

for address in addresses:
    parsed_address = parse_address(address)
    if parsed_address:
        print("Распарсенный адрес:")
        for key, value in parsed_address.items():
            print(f"{key}: {value}")
    else:
        print("Не удалось распарсить адрес:", address)


Можно было бы и не полениться вместо картинки вставить всё-таки текст, который требуется обработать. Можно ли с помощью модуля Питона исправить ошибки, не знаю. Попробовал ради интереса поставить эту задачу ИИ. Вот результат: Россия, Московская область, Ленинский район, г. Видное, ул. Заводская, д. 6, кв. 22 643, 163000, 78, Санкт-Петербург г., Офицерский пер., 86, 5 646602, Россия, Омская обл., Горьковский р-н, с. Астыровка, ул. Комсомольская, д. 17, кв. 1 656000, Россия, г. Барнаул, ул. Эмилии Алексеевой, д. 6, кв. 108. Теоретически, значит, можно.

@FoxFox проблема в том, что ИИ прекрасно справляется с небольшим объёмом работы, как в тестовом варианте, но мне нужно так обработать 100к строк файла, что весьма проблематично для ИИ

@FoxFox добавил текст вместо изображения

ИИ не думает, ИИ ищет в имеющемся у него словаре слов и меняет плохое слово на хорошее. Я имею опыт создания подобной базы данных, но она не работает сама по себе - 3,5 млн. слов я собирал руками. Если ИИ не работает, значит никто и ничто не работает без такого словаря.

Тут только шаблоны придумывать. Что-то удалять из строки заранее, что-то преобразовывать. Простого варианта не вижу.
